# Is there any defects for using same database prefix in WordPress for multiple sites?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, shared-hosting

I have now two sites using the same database prefix i.e., not other than `wp_` Now, the argument arises that if there are some known issues or defects for them being same. As if I install WordPress from Softaculous from cPanel then it doesn't generate the same prefix until we do it.

Comment: No.  But many devs use different prefixes for obfuscation and to make it easier to see it in a list of dbs.

Comment: If they're separate databases then it doesn't matter, they have nothing to do with eachother. If you use the same prefix in the same database then both sites would use the same database, would could cause problems if they have different themes, plugins or uploads.

Comment: See, I have two websites with two different databases and users (same prefix). So, will it affect?